# jquery how to remove a instance of a div if 2 are present?

Tags: jquery, filter, find

this question sounds a bit confusing, but here is what i have:

```
<div id="type2">
<img class="profile-img" src="75.jpg">
</div>
```

after i click on something it becomes like this:

```
<div id="type2">
<img class="profile-img" src="75.jpg">
<img class="profile-img" src="76.jpg">
</div>
```

what i want is to remove the first `img` instance if two are present.
basically to become:

```
<div id="type2">
<img class="profile-img" src="76.jpg">
</div>
```

i've tryed:

```
    if (item.lenght == 2) {
$('#type2').find('.profile-img:first').remove();
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work
thanks

edit:

thanks all. this answer is what worked for me from shifty:

```
if ($('#type2').find('.profile-img').size() >= 2) {
$('#type2').find('.profile-img:first').remove();
}
```

i did misspelled the `length` but still didn't want to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
if ($('#type2').find('.profile-img').size() >= 2) {
  $('#type2').find('.profile-img:first').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code `$('#type2').find('.profile-img:first').remove();` will definitely remove the first element with the class `profile-img` in the `#type2` selector, so things are broken elsewhere.

Is it just because you've misspelled the `length` attribute in `item.lenght`?

Comment: Yeah I thought so too. His selector is good, and as you pointed out he mis-spelled 'length'

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('.profile-img','#type2').eq(0).remove();
```

or

```
$('.profile-img','#type2').first().remove();
```

or

```
$('#type2 .profile-img:first').remove();
```

or

```
$('.profile-img:first','#type2').remove();
```

Comment: the eq(0) worked for me for some part of the code while the ('nth-child(1)') worked for me for other part of the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Your way should work fine.  I would guess the problem is the typo "lenght":

```
if (item.length == 2) {
    $('#type2').find('.profile-img:first').remove();
}
```

Assuming of course that `item` is defined and has a length of exactly 2.